# System.NullreferenceException for String split function

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, null, system

I am new to C# and modifying my first big program. I keep getting the following and and I am unsure how to New it up your help would be greatly appreciated

```
baseErrorCodes = New List(Of String)()
Dim errorCodeDescription As String = String.Empty
Dim baseCode As String
For Each errorCode As String In errorCodes
    Dim matchingBusinessRuleByResponseCode As BusinessRule = Me.DomainData.Common.BusinessRules _
        .FirstOrDefault(Function(businessRule) (businessRule.ApplicationSource = Me.BusinessRuleSource _
                                OrElse businessRule.ApplicationSource = "Maryland") _
                            AndAlso businessRule.ResponseCode = errorCode)

    baseCode = errorCode.Split("-")(0)
    If (matchingBusinessRuleByResponseCode IsNot Nothing) Then
        If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldSource)) Then
            fieldSource = matchingBusinessRuleByResponseCode.FieldSource
        End If
```

Error Message

[image: Error Message]

Comment: error is baseCode = errorCode.Split

Comment: The fact that this isn't C# may be a part of your confusion?

Answer (score 0):

So `errorCode` is null. This is the result of not finding a match and the default for string type is null. This is the expected behavior of `.FirstOrDefault()`.

To fix, add a check `If errorCode IsNot null Then ...` before calling `.Split()`.

or use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to handle.